# Como ter um objeto dentro de outro em uma API utilizando TypeScript + TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Eu tenho duas tabelas com relacionamento ManyToOne, onde a tabela Teachers so pode ter um e somente um da tabela Plans e Plans pode ter nenhum ou muitos da tabela Teachers.
Quando dar um select na Tabela teacher eu queria que os dados da tabela Plans viessem como objeto.
tipo:
Teacher:{
....dados,
plans {
.....
}
}
Como faço isso?

````
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import { Plan } from "./Plan";

@Entity('teachers')
export class Teacher{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id_teacher: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column()
    last_name: string;

    @Column()
    cpf: string;

    @Column()
    birthDate: Date;

    @Column()
    gender: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    hashPassword() {
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
    }

    @Column()
    pictureProfile: string;

    @Column()
    biography: string;

    @Column()
    linkedin: string;

    @Column()
    portifolio: string;

    @Column()
    contact: string;

    @Column()
    pix: string;

    @ManyToOne(type => Plan, teachers => Teacher)
    @JoinColumn({name: 'id_plan'})
    id_plan: Plan;
}```
````

import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Teacher } from "./Teacher";

@Entity('plans')
export class Plan{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id_plan: string;

```
@Column()
title: string;

@Column()
price: number;

@Column()
description: string;

@OneToMany(type => Teacher, plan => Plan)
teacher: Teacher[];
```

}

export const listTeachers = async(request: Request, response: Response) => {
const teacher = await getRepository(Teacher).find();

```
teacher.map((item) => {
    console.log(item.id_plan);
})
return response.json(teacher);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Descobri a resposta. É so escrever o nome da relação que no meu caso era id_plan.

const teacher = await getRepository(Teacher).find({relations: ["id_plan"]});